# What's happened with Sonar Natural Plugin?

Tags: nlp, sonarqube

Previously, I used the Sonar Natural Plugin in a old job. But now I search this plugin, however I don't found. What's happened with these plugin? He is deprecated?

Comment: Seems that it disappeared from plugins version matrix page on 2014.04.11 : http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=239371081&navigatingVersions=true it was still listed in previous version of the plugin version matrix page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is not maintained anymore, but you should ask directly to SonarSource. 
Regards.